# How to setup wild card 301 redirect that will remove URL parameters from index.php

Tags: apache, wildcard, http-status-code-301

ok I previously had some issues setting up a wild card redirect to strip parameters from an old url format that were non-seo friendly to our root. With the help of stackoverflow we've got it corrected and working but now I am experiencing issues with index.php?

Im seeing tons of duplicate urls in the engines using this url format index.php?cPath=# and Google is stressing me because they think its duplicate index pages.

I tried setting up this redirect in our htaccess but no go. It won't strip out the parameters or redirect it just duplicates the page with a valid 200 response.

RewriteRule ^index.php/.*$ /? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

I want to redirect anything with index.php?cPath=# to our root domain. Any ideas on how i can tackle this 301 redirect using a mod_rewrite on apache?

I've also just noticed that our site has another issue with this url format: 
domain.com/?cPath=#...

so now I also need to write a rewrite for domain.com/?cPath=#  I don't know where this one popped up from but I can see its going to cause issues hence the valid 200 response code it gives. The engines are really going to love me for this one.

Comment: ok we haven't gotten a response as of yet to our question so im posting an answer to the first half of my question.

Using a mod_rewrite I added the following to the htaccess file.

############################################
## Rewrite /index.php to the root home page

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

tested and works 100%. 

On to the second party of my question. Hopefully I will have a solution shortly.

Comment: we have solved the second part of our question. We actually found this one in stackoverflow. Here goes: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cPath=(.*)  then add the rule. RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]  voila!